# Can't change (enable/disable) features on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iis

I can't make any changes to Windows Features.
Even if I just enter in Windows Features and press <kbd>Ok</kbd> I get: "An error has occured. Not all of the features were successfully changed."

I noticed this while trying to install/uninstall IIS. If I try to install IIS from the Web Platform I get:

**[Windows package manager]**
The referenced assembly could not be found.
Operation failed with 0x80073701

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
I have tried
-> Startup Repair. It says it has found problems but is unable to solve them
-> System restore (but didn't had an early enough restore point)
:(

Comment: Can you install other stuff based on MSI?

Comment: @Nullable Yes... That error "0x800..." only seems to appear while trying to install IIS.

Comment: Make sure your .NET framework is up to date.

Comment: Possible idea for solution....http://d3dal3.blogspot.com/2010/07/unable-to-add-new-components-in-windows.html

Comment: @Moab, thanks, I've read that but I think I'll try a repair with the Windows DVD in.

Answer (score 4):

0x80073701 is "ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING".

Sounds like WinSxS (`%windir%\winsxs`) folder corruption, and/or missing files/links within.

Have you done a disk check (`chkdsk`)?  And/or and a System File Check (`sfc /scannow`).

Check the windows Event logs for related events to ensure you are not having something like disk or disk controller errors.

Make backups before repairing any disk errors. :)

Also, the [System Update Readiness Tool for Windows 7 (KB947821)](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=947821) can help diagnose problems related to a corrupted WinSxS.

You may also have to/want to re-apply your last service pack after the disks have been declared clean and correct.

Additional info [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/asiasupp/archive/2011/06/20/how-to-resolve-the-error-0x80073701-error-sxs-assembly-missing-when-you-are-installing-a-service-pack-or-hotfix.aspx), and [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/windows-updates-activation/163526-win7-sp1-upgrade-error_sxs_assembly_missing-0x80073701.html).

Comment: I've installed Readiness Tool, still same problem. System File Check shows everything is ok.

Comment: Is it ok for the sfc scan to only take like 1 second and say everything is ok?

Comment: @Cristy, absolutely not. Here it takes several minutes. On an SSD.

Comment: Done chkdsk, no problems found.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by reparing the windows using it's DVD. (Upgrade)
After the upgrade has finished it showed an error regarding side-by-side (SXS) stuff, but everything seems ok by now.